# Problem with Export - not able to save numbers in sceintific form

Tags: export

I have a complicated function that I want to plot using ListPlot but my computer crashes. I think it runs out of memory.

So, what i do now is to save each iteration in a .txt file.

For example i have Exp(-100x),

```
Table[ 
 ...
 f = OpenAppend["test.txt"];
 WriteString[f,N[x]," ",N[Exp[-100x]],"\n"];
 Close[f]; ,  {x, 0,1 0, 1/100}]
```

Now, at $x=0.12$, the value should be $6.14421$x$10^{-6}$ however if I look at the .txt file, i have

```
0.11 0.0000167017
0.12           -6
6.14421 10
0.13           -6
2.26033 10
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one simple trick:

```
WriteString[f, ExportString[{{N[x], N[Exp[-100 x]]}}, "Table"], "\n"];
```

Comment: very simple. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem with exporting numbers in 10^x form is that for typesetting purposes, *Mathematica* puts the `-6` on the line above the base number.

```
ToString[1.*^-6] // FullForm
```

> `"     -6\n1. 10"`

`\n` is the new line character.

If you want to export numbers in scientific form, here's a couple ways:

**Use `base + e + exponent`:**

```
NumberForm[1.*^-6, NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "e", #3}] &)]
```

> `"1.e-6"`

**Build a custom formatting function:**

```
 customformat[num_] := 
  ToString@NumberForm[num + 0., {10, 5}, NumberFormat -> 
   (Row[{#1, "*10^", If[ToExpression[(#3 /. "" -> "0")] < 0, "-", "+"], 
    StringPadLeft[StringReplace[ToString@#3, "-" -> ""], 3, "0"]}] &)]

customformat[1*^-6]
```

> `"1.00000*10^-006"`

Then `Export` to your heart's desire.